# How to do Zooming individually with two PerspectiveCameras with their two objects?

Tags: three.js

I have two objects in right and left side of window.[image]

I want to zoom those objects individually when I hover it.

```
 var itsLeftControls, itsRightControls;
  itsRightControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(itsRightCamera);
  itsLeftControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(itsLeftCamera);

 document.getElementById('SubContainerLeft').onmouseover = function () {
     aMouseOverActivate(itsLeftControls);
     aMouseOverDeactivate(itsRightControls);
    };

  document.getElementById('SubContainerRight').onmouseover = function () {
     aMouseOverActivate(itsRightControls);
     aMouseOverDeactivate(itsLeftControls);
   };

  function aMouseOverActivate(theControl)
   {
     theControl.zoomSpeed = 0.8;
   }

  function aMouseOverDeactivate(theControl)
   {
     theControl.zoomSpeed = 0.0;
   }

  function animateLeft()
  {
  requestAnimationFrame(animateLeft);
  renderLeft();
  }

 function renderLeft() 
 {
  itsLeftControls.update(); 
  itsLeftRenderer.render(itsLeftScene, itsLeftCamera);
 }

function animateRight()
  {
  requestAnimationFrame(animateRight);
  renderRight();
  }

 function renderRight() 
 {
  itsRightControls.update(); 
  itsRightRenderer.render(itsRightScene, itsRightCamera);
 }
```

if I hover in left side and try to zoom with mouse scrolling wheel, it is working fine. after that when I hover in right side, I can see that same zooming effect in right side also without scrolling mouse.
How to fix this?

Comment: show us the code for your controls

Comment: I am using TrackballControls here. First of all, I set Left and Right controls ZoomSpeed is 0 and call these above function while hovering each side.

Comment: @2pha - I zoomed in Left side and went to Right side. so, right side object was also zoomed in same like left side, automatically :(     I want both side object will work only when I will scroll mouse wheel.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this? I am still struggling here.

Comment: show us the code for your controls (how you are adding Trackball controls to each scene)

Comment: @2pha  Please check this code now.

Comment: See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TrachballControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) take a optional second argument that is the dom element onto which it will attach the mouse event listeners.
If this argument is not supplied, it will attach the event listeners to the document.
This means that both your trackball controls are listening for events on the document (rather than their respective containers which I think you want.)
So just send your scene container divs as the second arguments to TrackballControlls and you should be good to go.

```
var leftContainer = document.getElementById('SubContainerLeft');
var rightContainer = document.getElementById('SubContainerRight');

var itsRightControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(itsRightCamera, rightContainer);
var itsLeftControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(itsLeftCamera, leftContainer);
```